# Sorting data in work with pattern in genexus according to a particular attribute

Tags: genexus

How to sort data in work with pattern in genexus according to a particular attribute? please give me the code segment for putting in load event.

Answer (score 0):

In the pattern object, right-button click in the object you want to edit, Add > Orders, and then create a new order with the desired attribute.

[image]

Comment: Marcos, Thanks for reply. I will try it and let you know. hope it works.

Comment: Hi Marcos it worked when i set sorting order to be ascending, but i need it in Descending order. I have tried by setting its Ascending property to be false. but its not working please help.